# Create empty array inside Scripting.Dictionary object using AutoIt

Tags: arrays, dictionary, autoit

Is there a way I can create an array inside a dictionary this way (without creating a variable first):

```
Local $myDictionary = ObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary")
$myDictionary.Add("firstDictionary", ObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary")) ;this is ok
$myDictionary.Add("firstarray", []) ;this is wrong

_ArrayAdd($myDictionary.Item("firstArray"), "first element in firstArray")
_ArrayAdd($myDictionary.Item("firstArray"), "second element in firstArray")
```

This caused a popup with "Error in expression"
Shouldn't this [] return an empty sized array?

And for some reason I cannot add elements when an array is inside a dictionary:

```
Local $newArray[1]
Local $myDictionary = ObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary")

_ArrayAdd($newArray,101) ;this is ok
$myDictionary.Add("firstArray", $newArray)

;_ArrayAdd($myDictionary.Item("firstArray"), 102)  ; this is wrong
_ArrayAdd(($myDictionary.Item("firstArray")), 102)  ; this does not change the dictionary array
_ArrayDisplay(($myDictionary.Item("firstArray")))  ; this still shows 101
```

Comment: For future reference, this is also asked on AutoIt Forums [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/166397-create-empty-array-inside-scriptingdictionary-object/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to create an array within a dictionary object, except by using a function that returns an array (StringSplit is a common choice).

Passing a dictionary item ByRef like that is interesting.

Because you have to enclose it in parenthesis (like `($dict.Item("foo"))`) it evaluates the expression, so what you are passing is not actually a reference at all. There's no reason why you can't pass it without those parenthesis in theory, but AutoIt doesn't have that functionality yet (and from what Jon has said in the past, updating the COM interface code is a nightmare).

Solutions are to upgrade to the latest beta and use maps, which are a dictionary like collection built into AutoIt.

Alternatively, you have to use 3 lines, create a temporary array and then reassign it after adding:

```
Local $a = $dict.Item("foo")
_ArrayAdd($a, "world")
$dict.Item("foo") = $a
```